# Can urinary tract infection be treated by inducing urination?

Tags: treatment-options, effectiveness, urine, urine-test, urinary-tract-infect-uti

Urinary tract infection causes dysconfort by giving the urge to urinate even with empty bladder. The one time I had the symptoms (blood in urine, urge to urinate again), I forced myself into drinking too much water so my bladder filled again in a few minutes, so I could urinate. I repeated the process during the course of a few hours, and each time the urine was clearer, and never again I had the symptoms (this was about 4 years ago). Today my girlfriend had the same symptoms, and she used the same procedure. She also went to the hospital, and due to excessive urination, the urine sample she collected for the examination was water-clear. Results came out with no indication of infection, so the doctor sent us home without antibiotics.

Is there any study or established knowledge that forcing urination is an effective treatment for UTI? Should I be worried she might still need antibiotics?